# Custom Password Reset or where are the dlls for DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I'm working on a custom PasswordReset and SendPassword. While doing so, I found the existing controls at the **Website\admin\Security**, the reference is pointing to `DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Security` namespace.  So I went to look for it in the platform source code, but couldn't find any projects (or dlls).
Is there a separate solution some where? 
Please help me solve the mystery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that these files are part of the the "Website" directory they are NOT compiled into a DLL.  The code for these files are alongside the actual .ascx files within the admin\security folder and you can make changes as you need to.

NOTE: I don't recommend changing the core unless you really need to, as you have to remember to always change it in future upgrades.